# Datatables responsive and rowreorder in the same table not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've a problem using datatables with Responsive addon-on and Rowreorder together.

This is my code:

```
var table = $('#table01').DataTable( {
    responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column',
            target: 0
        }
    },
    rowReorder: {
        selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
    },
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    scrollCollapse: false,
    scrollY: false,
    columnDefs: [
        { orderable: false, className: 'control', targets: 0 },
        { orderable: false, className: 'reorder', targets: 1 },
        { orderable: false, targets: '_all' }
    ]
});
```

but i get this table:
Firt column: CORRECT, i see "+" indicate responsive plugin is ok. It works.
Second column: Ordering seems to be ok, but if drag-drop rows, it reverse back to original position
Also the ordering icon inside `thead` is in the first column (not the second).

I've made a little example: http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/2574/

[image]